# OpenCV Error: Null array pointer Java

Tags: java, opencv, nullpointerexception

I am runing web-cam, trying to detect object in real time and I have this code running. It gives me error at `video.main(video.java:92)` - `CvRect sq = cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0);` But I am checking `if(ptr != null)` . I don't understand why.

```
CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
CvSeq contours = new CvContour(null);          
noOfContors = cvFindContours(imgbin, storage, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, new CvPoint(0,0));


 for (ptr = contours;  ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {     
    if(ptr != null){
         CvRect sq = cvBoundingRect(ptr, 0);
         if(sq.height()*sq.width() > minAreaa && sq.height()* sq.width() < maxAreaa){
            p1.x(sq.x());
            p2.x(sq.x()+sq.width());
            p1.y(sq.y());
            p2.y(sq.y()+sq.height());
            cvRectangle(img1, p1, p2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0);
        } 
    }
}
```

In command window:

```
 OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL array pointer is passed) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp, line 2382
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp:2382: error: (-27) NULL array pointer is passed

    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.cvBoundingRect(Native Method)
    at video.main(video.java:92)
```

Comment: Error mentions `NULL` **array** pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding an additional condition in `for` loop, but still don't know if it's a proper way to handle it:

```
CvSeq contours1 = new CvContour(null);
for (ptr = contours;  ptr != null && cvFindContours(imgbin, storage, contours1, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, new CvPoint(0,0)) != 0; ptr = ptr.h_next()){ .....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
 for (ptr = contours; ptr != null && !ptr.isNull(); ptr = ptr.h_next()) {
```

the !ptr.isNull() fixes the null pointer error.